# Joomla 3.8.13 show php errors without error line number

Tags: php, joomla

My Joomla system reports this error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)

It does not report the line and file where the PHP error is generated.

in my configuraton.php file I have:

```
public $error_reporting = 'maximum';
```

I can't understand why this behavior, Can anyone help me?

Comment: We need to see the script that is generating this error.  Go into the administrator/backend to the global setting and turn on the debugging / error reporting settings.  Without any code to look at, volunteers can only make wild guesses at what you may have done.  At the moment, you question is at risk of being Closed as Off-topic: Why isn't my code working.  https://www.joomlabeginner.com/blog/tutorials/63-how-to-enable-error-reporting-in-joomla

Comment: I see that you have a wordpress stack exchange account, you may like to create a [joomla.se] stack exchange account if you are going to be using Joomla.

Comment: @mickmackusa my problem is just that: i've enabled debugging but doesn't tell me which script generates the error

Comment: I have the same problem on Joomla 3.9.20 it only shows the error text not the code line.

Answer (score 0):

You have it misspelled.  Please update that line to:

```
public $error_reporting = 'maximum';
                                ^--typo
```

Comment: I was wrong to report the line of code, the value is set correctly, and the error is displayed to me as in the image of the problem

Comment: If you have made an error in posting your question details, please edit your question so that it accurately represents your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make it

public $error_reporting = 'development';

Comment: nothing change, the error show me without line from generate error.